# Two-colouring the two-sphere

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory, colorings

Suppose that $S^2$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Is there a function $f \colon S^2 \to \{0,1\}$ so that, for any orthonormal basis $(u,v,z)$, exactly one of the values $f(u)$, $f(v)$, and $f(z)$ equals $1$?

Comment: This looks very much like a Hadwiger-Nelson type problem for the unit sphere (at least in the following sense: if the unit sphere is $3$-colorable with forbidden distance equal to that from the pole to the equator, then your question has a positive answer). Such problems are notoriously difficult. But one thing that can easily be said is that there is a compactness phenomenon: if the answer is “no”, then there is a finite witness to this fact.

Comment: It is known that the unit-sphere with this forbidden distance is 4-chromatic; see Simmons: The chromatic number of the sphere, 1976, or for a more recent, independent proof, https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0486. Some newer results are in https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08666.

Comment: I think that this question is more similar to the finite version of Steinhaus's problem, see this manuscript: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603235.

Comment: Compare Gleason's theorem `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem`

Comment: If you're only plugging in normal vectors, why do you need the function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You should inform that this question is [crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757057/573047) to avoid duplication of effort by people answering on different sites.

Answer (score 50):

The answer is no.  This was proven by Kochen and Specker in 1967 in the context of quantum mechanics, refuting a notion of hidden variables.  They found 117 points on the sphere that cannot be assigned values 0 and 1 in the requested way.  (This is a finite witness that Gro-Tsen alluded to.  And following up on Gerald Edgar's comment, this discrete collection demonstrates a corollary of Gleason's continuous result.)

For a nice explanation and bibliographic details, see this *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* [entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kochen-specker/) which also mentions subsequent results requiring fewer points and simpler $\mathbb{R}^4$ examples.

Comment: And for a direct reference to an explicit construction using only 33 points, Citeseer has a PDF of Peres, A. (1991). [Two simple proofs of the Kochen-Specker theorem](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=94abdca6caae890e351114f420aa65a81b15fe76). Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, 24(4), L175.

Comment: Unbelievable. This means that the chromatic number of the sphere with this radius was proved to be four a decade before Simmons's paper in quantum mechanical terminology.